How can I fix scripts in WSL2-Linux-Kernel:pahole-flags.sh not found and syntax error in mconf-cfg.sh

I'm trying to modify the kernel,but scripts that indeed exists were reported missing.I've checked the file permissions and library dependencies，but the error remains.
version:
my wsl:Ubuntu-24.04LTS   kernel:linux-msft-wsl-5.15.153.1

Sorry, but we really cannot help you debug code we do not see. Please [edit] your question and add the actual scripts you are trying to run. That said, given the fact that your screenshot suggests the text is garbled, my first guess is that you have used a Windows tool to edit the files, so they now have windows style line endings. Try running dos2unix or sed -i 's/\r//g' on the offending files (no idea what those are, you will need to find the relevant Makefile, that is the most likely culprit).

In order to modify the kernel, one must download (apt source ) the kernel source, and unpack it.

@terdon Thank you very much.It turned out that windows style line endings were be to blame.And I apologize for  adding no actual scripts.:)
